# Como o laravel sabe qual tabela do meu bd será usada pra minha operação?

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma tabela no meu bd chamada animais_perdidos, foi criada sem uso de migrations.

Criei uma classe no laravel pra ela:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AnimalPerdido extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'id_usuario', 'lat', 'lng', 'id_tipo_pet', 'raca', 'id_sexo', 'data', 'possui_identificador', 'id_cores', 'informacoes_adicionais' 
    ];

}
```

Criei um controller pra retornar todos os dados dessa minha tabela:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App/AnimalPerdidoController;

class AnimalPerdidoController extends Controller
{
    //Retorna todos os cadastros
    public function index()
    {
        $animaisPerdidos = AnimalPerdido::->get();
        return response()->json($animaisPerdidos);
    }
}
```

E na minha rota:

```
Route::get('animalperdido', 'AnimalPerdidoController@index');
```

Como posso falar pro laravel que a minha tabela animais_perdidos usará esse modelo/controller?

Comment: Buscou na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models)? Qual parte ficou em dúvida?

Comment: Dentro do seu Controller, coloque: `use App\AnimalPerdido;` isso será suficiente pro seu controller identificar seu model.

Comment: Então, minha dúvida eu postei na pergunta.. Gostaria de saber como o laravel vai aplicar o controller/modelo que eu criei na tabela que já existe no banco de dados, pois não estou usando migrations... Como ele encontraria qual tabela ele vai atuar?

Comment: Então, minha dúvida é mais saber como que meu controller vai saber que ele tem que buscar os dados na tabela animais_perdidos, pois não foi utilizado migrations.

Comment: Só declarar uma propriedade protected $table = 'animais_perdidos' é suficiente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente colocar uma variável `protected $table = 'nome_da_sua_tabela`:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AnimalPerdido extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'id_usuario', 'lat', 'lng', 'id_tipo_pet', 'raca', 'id_sexo', 'data', 'possui_identificador', 'id_cores', 'informacoes_adicionais' 
    ];

    protected $table = animais_perdidos

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tomei por base na [Documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models) oficial, mas acrescentei umas notas:

> ## Nomes das tabelas
>
> Note que não dissemos qual foi o nome da tabela do modelo `Flight`. Por convenção, o  plural da classe em `snake_case` (em vez de maiúsculas, usado um _ como separador), mas você pode definir uma outra tabela manualmente no model desta forma, via uma propriedade **table**:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
>     namespace App;
>     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>     class Flight extends Model
>     {
>         /**
>          * Aqui vai a tabela que é associada com o model.
>          *
>          * @var string
>          */
>         protected $table = 'my_flights'; 
>     }
> ```

Em resumo, na declaração da classe se acrescenta esta propriedade:

```
protected $table = 'nome_da_tabela';
```

já com o nome da tabela em `snake_case`.

**Notas:**

- Quando a documentação fala em plural, é o "plural burro", só acrescenta um `s` no final da string

  OBSERVAÇÃO: tem uma [classe de pluralização](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-plural) para inglês, o que é uma péssima idéia, e obviamente em português vai ficar terrível se não for adaptada.
- A conversão em `snake_case` é basicamente uma troca de maiúsculas por minúsculas, e inserção de um `_` para separar as palavras: `AbcDef` => `abc_def`